# How can I add an onclick to a generic control in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I want the programmer to pass a Control to a method, and then I want to add an onclick to it. But control doesn't have an Attributes property. Is there an interface or something deriving from Control that I can use, to add an onclick attribute to it?

Note that I want to add a javascript onclick (clientclick?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl` class - it inherits from `System.Web.UI.Control` and has an `Attributes` property.

Answer (score 1):

D'oh I fixed it now, the solution is to use a WebControl rather than a Control.